# iTunes Connect download stats

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is it normal for the ITC Sales Trend to take a few days to kick in? We've published our first app and it went live yesterday morning. I know from the Game Center scores that there are at least 100 people playing it, but ITC shows 11 downloads.

What's more strange is that it shows data for USA, Canada, Columbia & Mexico, but there are quite a few of my friends and friends of friends playing, who are in Australia. In fact I would assume that a majority of the players are in Australia, so is there perhaps some kind of lag on stats in our region?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes,  I found that ITC could not provide enough information. 
Instead I am using Google Analystics for iOS, which event can provide realtime data. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

Comment: That sounds good, but unfortunately the framework we used to compile the game won't support it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data has updated overnight. It's now showing stats from countries in Europe & Asia, in addition to the North & Central Americas ones from yesterday. So I think I just had to be a little more patient.

Comment: Although I've got data from different countries now, I would still expect the Australian figures to be higher compared to the US ones, so I'm suspecting that there may be some kind of lag for non-American regions. Can anyone confirm this?